# JS: make browser select-all (Chrome, at least)

Tags: svg, cross-domain

I am playing around various ways to try circumvent Cross-origin issues when loading (node, not img) SVG into a local html file. There's no reason I can't just simply use a web-server, but this is for fun/educational purposes.

So, current experiment is this: inside the SVG which is embedded via `<object>` tag, I have a script which makes a new `<text>` and writes the entire SVG there. The idea was to write it down, delete all other nodes and make a select-all copy the entire text in the window (it's a pop-up window) and then return to original HTML document to paste the text in and then make my inline SVG!

The parts I have working are all the way up to the 'select-all' piece. I know that we have the ability to select text out of a `<textarea>` with .select(), but inside of SVG that's not a thing. Now I'm stumped whether it's even possible to dispatch the Cmd+A keys , or anything, in order to get the browser to select-all.

Alternatively I can just change the .svg to '.txt' which would make my pop-up-copy strategy at least work past the select-all part, but if it takes post-processing my svg manually then it defeats the purpose of these experimentations!

Ideas welcome! :)

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Even after contemplating your post for ten minutes, I have no idea what it is you are trying to do. Try again, maybe with a bit of code, even if it is not executable?

Comment: I don't think code would help much, but maybe a diagram could. What I want to do is simply not have to copy-paste my SVG into my local HTML file , I would like it to reference the SVG with a tag but have some JavaScript take that tag and embed the inline SVG from it. The problem is the CORS policy with local files - but I wish to hack around it any which way so as to still accomplish this goal. It's just for personal exercise. So- if a script inside the object-embedded SVG can produce a text body of that SVG, maybe I can copy/paste the text ? Diagram coming later!